# Specified key was too long: max key lenth is 3072 bytes

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I need your help with this, i already have all relation tables instantiated but when im going to create the relationship table it sends me "Error: 1071 Specified key was too long: max key lenth is 3072 bytes"

My code until now:

```
CREATE TABLE tablahechos(
id_almacenf VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
id_productof VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
id_categoriaf VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
id_transaccionf VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
id_tipo_serviciof VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
id_mensajerof VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
id_clientef VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
id_tiempo_fecha_orden VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
id_tiempo_fecha_reserva_entrada VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
id_tiempo_fecha_reserva_salida VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
id_tiempo_fecha_inventario_entrada VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
id_tiempo_fecha_inventario_salida VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
id_tiempo_fecha_envio VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
id_tiempo_fecha_facturacion VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
id_tiempo_fecha_cancelada VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
para_regalo VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
monto_unitario VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
monto_total VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
cantidad VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id_almacenf, id_productof, id_categoriaf, id_transaccionf, 
id_tipo_serviciof, id_mensajerof, id_clientef, id_tiempo_fecha_orden,
id_tiempo_fecha_reserva_entrada, id_tiempo_fecha_reserva_salida,
id_tiempo_fecha_inventario_entrada, id_tiempo_fecha_inventario_salida,
id_tiempo_fecha_envio, id_tiempo_fecha_facturacion, id_tiempo_fecha_cancelada),
CONSTRAINT FK1
  FOREIGN KEY (id_almacenf)
  REFERENCES almacendim (id_almacen),
CONSTRAINT FK2
  FOREIGN KEY (id_productof)
  REFERENCES productodim (id_producto),
CONSTRAINT FK3
  FOREIGN KEY (id_categoriaf)
  REFERENCES categoriadim (id_categoria),
CONSTRAINT FK4
  FOREIGN KEY (id_transaccionf)
  REFERENCES transacciondim (id_transaccion),
CONSTRAINT FK5
  FOREIGN KEY (id_mensajerof)
  REFERENCES mensajerodim (id_mensajero),
CONSTRAINT FK6
  FOREIGN KEY (id_clientef)
  REFERENCES clientedim (id_cliente),
CONSTRAINT FK7
  FOREIGN KEY (id_tiempo_fecha_orden)
    REFERENCES tablahechos (id_tiempo_fecha_orden),
CONSTRAINT FK8
  FOREIGN KEY (id_tiempo_fecha_reserva_entrada)
  REFERENCES tablahechos (id_tiempo_fecha_reserva_entrada),
CONSTRAINT FK9 
  FOREIGN KEY (id_tiempo_fecha_reserva_salida)
  REFERENCES tablahechos (id_tiempo_fecha_reserva_salida),
CONSTRAINT FK10
  FOREIGN KEY (id_tiempo_fecha_inventario_entrada)
  REFERENCES tablahechos (id_tiempo_fecha_inventario_entrada),
CONSTRAINT FK11 
  FOREIGN KEY (id_tiempo_fecha_inventario_salida)
  REFERENCES tablahechos (id_tiempo_fecha_inventario_salida),
CONSTRAINT FK12
  FOREIGN KEY (id_tiempo_fecha_envio)
    REFERENCES tablahechos (id_tiempo_fecha_envio),
CONSTRAINT FK13
  FOREIGN KEY (id_tiempo_fecha_facturacion)
  REFERENCES tablahechos (id_tiempo_fecha_facturacion),
CONSTRAINT FK14
  FOREIGN KEY (id_tiempo_fecha_cancelada) 
  REFERENCES tablahechos (id_tiempo_fecha_cancelada)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

i already change the charset to `latin1` and nothing happens, i know my primary key is too long but it must be that way. What should i do?

Comment: Shorten your primary key. If it's too long, it's too long, and you must shorten it. I'm not sure what part of that would be unclear. If your primary key needs to be that long, it would indicate to me that your database is poorly designed and I'd be looking for a way to change it.

Comment: Unfortunately `The InnoDB internal maximum key length is 3500 bytes, but MySQL itself restricts this to 3072 bytes. This limit applies to the length of the combined index key in a multi-column index. `

Comment: I would give it some sort why you implement such a huge and strange primary key. This is usually not required, in contrary. You should have a very simple primary key consisting of typically a single column value. Plus whatever other indexes you need for specific queries.

Comment: @KenWhite actually it's a datawarehouse design, i already have all dimention tables and this error appears when im going to create de center fact table

Comment: One thing you can do is to reduce the length of the columns - 255 is too much for many IDs. I ran into a similar case where I could not reduce the number of columns, but I then realized I could reduce their sizes from 255 to varchar(60), which got me over the hump

Answer (score 4):

*Fortunately*, there is a maximum key length, because your primary key is way too long.

I would strongly suggest adding an auto incremented primary key to the table:

```
CREATE TABLE tablahechos (
    id_hechos int not null auto_increment primary key,
    id_almacenf VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    . . .
```

What does this give you?  Well, this simplified primary key helps in several ways:

- It makes it *much* easier to find a single row in the table.
- It greatly simplifies any foreign key references.
- It provides a mechanism of determining the order of row insertion.

If you want to build a key on all those columns, you can shorten the length of the columns to something like 32.  Do "id" column *really* need to be 255 characters in length?  If so, you should replace them with numeric ids in those tables as well.  In fact, you should probably be using integer ids for all these columns, with joins to look up additional information about them.

Comment: I did it, but now sends me `Error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint`. Btw, the foreign keys already are primary keys at their tables.

Comment: @IvanG4Life . . . I would suggest that you ask another question, including the code that you have written.  Foreign key constraints to numeric primary keys are used very, very often.

Answer (score 2):

Normalize.

I suspect that most of those ids are repeated a lot in this table.  Build other tables that map VARCHAR(255) to/from MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED.  The use that number instead of the string.

Propagate that change throughout the rest of the tables and FOREIGN KEYs.  The entire dataset will be much smaller, and possibly faster.

A pattern for a simple Normalization is

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    foo_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (foo_name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

You mentioned shrinking to latin1; with this change you can go back to utf8.