# asp.net core 2 showing specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on .net core 2. I am using mysql as database. When i am writing the following code `dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();` it is generating me an error

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes'

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            // ===== Create tables ======
            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

I am able to generate roleclaims, roles, userclaims, users successfully.
I am using applicationDbcontext which is extending IdentityDbContext.

How can this error be resolved.
need help thanks in advance.

Comment: Somewhere you are trying to create a table with a primary key which is [way too long](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29319026/314291)

Comment: @StuartLC ok so what should i do for this, can u suggest me. I m stucked.

Answer (score 0):

I also face this issue what i do is

1. Open command prompt and go to project location then run following command

   dotnet ef migrations script -o initial.sql
2. It will generate sql, open the file and remove all VARCHAR(767) with VARCHAR(100)

run the sql in sqlyog/workbench you first migration will be created & now you can continue work.

and for rest of migrations make sure do not make primary key varchar for greater length or use int

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix, but a simple workaround when Irfan's answer does not apply.

After receiving this error, I addressed the potential issue of keys from combined fields exceeding the limit by setting their max sizes in the migration Up method - this did not help.

I generated a script in Package Manager Console with
`script-migration -o initial.sql -context MyDbContextName` and saw that there were no exceptional varchars in the stored migrations.

I gave up on a code solution and did this: -

1. In MySQL Workbench, create the empty schema (database) by
   right-clicking in an empty part of the Schemas tab and choosing Create Schema.
2. In Package Manager Console,
   run `update-database -context ApplicationDbContext`.